# How to relocate Attribute on product page?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento1.9.3.1

I am developing my first e-commerce website on **magento 1.9.3.1**. In main product page, i like to **move / relocated few attributes** such as **SKU**, Manufacturer and so on from Additional Tab to Under Product Title.

How would I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `view.phtml` file under your active theme directory.

Open following file in your fav editor.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Around 50 you will find , `<h1>` tag, that will be product name.

if you want to add SKU then please add following code underneath of H1 tag (product name).

```
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?></h1>
```

If you want to display other variables on product page then you can use `$_product` to get attribute data.

**Edited**

```
$attributeCode= 'manufacturer';
$manufacturerLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product);
$_manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getF‌​rontend()->getValue(‌​$_product);
echo $manufacturerLabel; echo $_manufacturerName;

$attributeCode= 'mfrnumber';
$mfrnumberLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getFrontend()->getLabel($_product);
$_mfrnumberName = $_product->getAttributeText($attributeCode);

echo $mfrnumberLabel; 
echo $_mfrnumberName;
```

Comment: Thanks. using the same code how can i show manufacturers? replaced getSku with getManufacturer and I only display ID number and no text . also how do i show Label with the value : ex : 
SKU : 1234    Manufacturer : abc   mfr.no : 5678

Comment: check my edited answer @tonysar

Comment: Thanks. I wrapped this code around <?php ?> , after inserting this into view.phtml file . i get blank page. I can not spot any problem with this code.

Comment: provide your `view.phtml` source code

Comment: im using RWD , i have not altered View.phtml in any way . just copied and pasted the code into the file in correct location. if i remove first echo statement in manufacturer block , it works ok .